# It Lays on its Side Riddle

Tags: riddle

I have several faces

I lay on my side

If you empty me out I have nothing to hide

Line my faces and you’ll see my figure

Together the lines create a figure with eight

What am I?

Answer (score 4):

You are

> A [Rubin vase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubin_vase)

I have several faces

> A vase figure formed by two faces. Does two count as "several"? Hmm...

I lay on my side

> A cup stands in the middle. Not on its side generally, but I'm sure you can achieve the same effect by depicting the cup on its side?

If you empty me out I have nothing to hide

> In a whited-out image you can clearly see the figures.

Line my faces and you’ll see my figure

> The faces form the figure of a cup.

Together the lines create a figure with eight

> The number 8 looks like an hourglass or a cup.

Answer (score -4):

Correct answer:

> Cube - a cube has 8 edges

Comment: I think a cube has 12 edges?

Comment: A cube has 6 faces, 12 edges, and 8 vertices. Sorry, but given this answer I think it's a bad riddle.